# Duplicate domains in Google Webmaster tools and its effect on Analytics

Tags: web, google-analytics, google-search-console

I own a site and I see both the www and non www sites in my Webmaster Tools Dashboard. I'm in the process of redirecting one to the other, but I've noticed different statistics for each site from search queries.

In reference to Google Analytics, is the sum of the two statistics an accurate representation of traffic to the site from search? Or is only one site influencing Analytics?

I would also appreciate any advice on best practices regarding managing the two sites in Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics tracks "pages" and not domains.
As long as your pages have tracking code on them, Google Analytics will report on them no matter what domain they are served from.

Hope this information helps!

Ankit